# Best way to backup Windows Phone App database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I'm planning to implement a backup/restore feature for my app, but not sure what way is the best and most efficient way to do it.
I can either copy the entire sdf file to the cloud or convert it to xml ? the easy way is to copy sdf file but is it a good way ? I mean exposing the database file considering the app is not free and its a paid app !
Can I encode the sdf file or password protect it !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, It explains it here how to protect data in a database on Windows Phone.
The database is encrypted using AES-128 and the password is hashed using SHA-256.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202861(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Usingconnectionstrings

```
 // Create the data context.
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext("Data Source='isostore:/mydb.sdf';Password='securepassword';");

// Create an encrypted database after confirming that it does not exist.
if (!db.DatabaseExists()) db.CreateDatabase();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own upload endpoint, or you could use the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff621310.aspx) and upload the file to the user's SkyDrive (not a secure option). So you end up with the need for your own backend - for example, build a WCF service through which you can pipe serialized data or simply have a secure upload endpoint that differentiates users.

Comment: I am using Live SDK at the moment , my question is that if uploading sdf file itself is a good idea or I have to implement my own file format or data type !

Comment: Your own file format or data type is not going to help you unless you also implement a security mechanism to go with it.